meaning of "It might fix ya." here
This is the script of a video clip of a stand-up comedy. (Nicole and Rebecca are audience members)

Comedian : What's up, beautiful? How you doing? Oh! Who is this?
What's your name, love?
Nicole : Nicole
Comedian : Nicole. Nice to meet you Nicole. Who are you here with?
Nicole : My friend Rebecca.
Comedian : Rebecca? What's up, Rebecca? How old are you, Nicole?
Nicole : 33
Comedian : 33. Have you done molly?
Nicole : Not yet.
Comedian : Not yet? It might fix ya.
Audience at Balcony : (laughter)
Comedian : Shut up, balcony. Shut up! Can I ask what your condition is?
Nicole : CP
Comedian : CP?
Nicole : Yep.
Comedian : And Rebecca, where did you meet?
Rebecca : We've been friends forever. I also have CP.
Comedian : You also have CP?
Rebecca : Yes.
Comedian : Where? Ah, Nicole, don't let her be that cool. Don't let
her be that cool. She didn't earn it.

I wonder what the meaning of "It might fix ya" is in this context.

Thanks for the link, but could you include more of the context in the text of the question?

@JamesK Thank you, but I'm currently outside, so I'll edit the question as soon as I get home.

I’m voting to close this question because it requires viewing a video.

@MichaelHarvey I appreciate your comment, but without watching the video, it might be difficult to understand the context just from the script.

We don't like following links to view videos. The link might fail because the video is removed, or the content might be annoying in some way - content may trigger cultural sensitivities, or be generationally sensitive (juvenile teen humour) This site prefers questions in text form.

@MichaelHarvey Sorry. I'll edit the OP as soon as possible.

@MichaelHarvey And I hope this question doesn't upset someone's feelings.

It is a "pronunciation spelling" of "It might fix you".
The stand-up comedian is interacting with an audience member named Nicole with CP (cerebral palsy, a condition that affects movement and posture and people with CP often use wheelchairs)  He asks "Have you done molly?"  (molly=molecular MDMA, a pure form of the drug ecstasy) Nicole answers "not yet!". He takes a moment, and then comments "it (the drug) might fix you".  This is very rude as it implies she is "broken".  But he is "allowed" to be so rude because he is the comedian, and part of the act is that he can say shocking things.

Thank you very much. So, does "broken" in your response mean "subdued completely, CRUSHED, SORROWFUL (due to her CP)" and "fix" means "enhance mood and create a sense of euphoria"? Or does "fix mean "cure (CP)" here?

I would note that the enclosure of 'allowed' in double quotes is an indication that the statement is controversial. I will also note that Britons often note that many North Americans use 'spaz' jocularly as a noun or verb meaning 'clumsy' or 'behave clumsily' respectively. In Britain, this is about as offensive as you can get.

Are comedians "allowed" to e.g. re-tell jokes from Der Stürmer?

@MichaelHarvey I see. Would it be best for me to delete this question?

@qna - you must decide that. You are not personally insulting disabled people; however some people may be 'triggered'.

@MichaelHarvey. Okay, Thank you very much. I tried, but I cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.

@qna the latter.  "Broken" in the sense of "not functioning correctly" and "fix"  in the sense of repair. His basic schtick is saying things that are shockingly rude.  It is shockingly rude to suggest that Nicole is broken, or that mdma could repair her.

@JamesK I understood. Thank you very much.
